# Help identifying a dessert from a stock image

Tags: dessert, food-identification

I am trying to identify the dessert shown in this stock image. It appears to be some sort of cake with chocolate base and grainy looking cream on top, maybe cheese based.

According to the descriptions I was able to find online it is "Cherry Cream Cake" or "Chocolate cream cake with cherries" but I am hoping that someone here could recognize it and share more details.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think you already reached the best possible detail in your description, by saying it's a layer of cake with a layer of grainy cream on it. Any further answers would be guesses, but it would be impossible to tell just from the photo which one is right and which is wrong. So I'm afraid it's a subjective question.

Comment: Are you sure that's not just regular cream cheese icing with powdered sugar on top?

Comment: I am starting to think it is brownie base with cheese cake layer and powdered sugar on top of it yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it looks like this is a cheesecake later on top of a chocolate cake later.

Another possibility is a Chocolate Tres Leches Cake, recipe here : https://www.plainchicken.com/chocolate-tres-leches-cake/